# My GIFs are not getting displayed in child component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a simgle page app which displays GIF's > I am able to successfully fetch the images and i am also passing them to a child component after fetching them. But they are not getting displayed properly. Their alt property gets dispayed.
[enter image description here][1]

```
class Result extends Component{
    RenderImage(url,title){
        return(
            <div><img src={(url)} alt={title} width="100" height="50" /></div>
        )   
    }
    render(){
        let imgs = [];
        if(this.props.images!=null)
        {
            imgs = this.props.images;
        }
        return(
            <div>
                GIF's
                <div className="container col-12">
                    {
                        imgs.map(image => this.RenderImage(image.url,image.title))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Result;
``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNGHk.png
```

Comment: did you try without extra brackets in src?
`<img src={url} ..`

Comment: Yes I tried using that and also using ```require(url)```

Comment: how the url of the gifs look like?

Comment: Sample url https://giphy.com/gifs/hello-hi-dzaUX7CAG0Ihi

Comment: I think it should be this https://media.giphy.com/media/dzaUX7CAG0Ihi/source.gif

Comment: Sample url https://giphy.com/gifs/foxhomeent-hello-friday-mrs-doubtfire-28GHfhGFWpFgsQB4wR

Comment: go to that link, click on "media", and then click on "copy" next to the source field

Comment: the link that you sent, is not the link for the gif file, its the link to the page

Comment: The urls i am getting are like commented earlier then how do convert them to the desired ones in code

Comment: It seems i have used wrong url from json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks a bit confusing, I tried to make it a bit easier to read.

Make sure you use correct url from response, it should end with `.gif`

```
const Result extends Component{
  render(){
   return (
     <div>
      GIF's
       <div className="container col-12">
         {this.props.images.map(({url,title})=> <img src={url} alt={title} />)}
       </div>
      </div>
     )
    }
}
export default Result;
```

Comment: Just getting started with react. Thanks for the help